# set np.array of strings as return-type using numpy.typing

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

I have a function which returns a (1d) numpy array of strings e.g class-predictions.

I can make it return a NDArray of floats (for e.g the probabilities)

```py
import numpy.typing as npt
def predict_proba(self,X:csr_matrix)->npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    ...
    return pred_proba
```

but I struggle to make it a "string". If I parse `object` like

```py
import numpy.typing as npt
def predict(self,X:csr_matrix)->npt.NDArray[object]:
```

then I get a warning  saying

```bash
Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
  Type "object" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
    "object" is incompatible with "generic"Pylance
```

What do I do there? I cannot find anything in the [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.DTypeLike) apart from the `Any` type, but that kinda ommits the idea.

**EDIT**

I think using `NDArray[np.dtype(str)]` worked (I'm not getting any errors and the code works). But I feel it's a bit of a hack/not the right way?

Comment: [`numpy.str_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html?highlight=str_#numpy.str_)?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Mechanic Pig`'s suggestion:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def get_array(strings:List[str]) -> npt.NDArray[np.str_]:
    a:npt.NDArray[np.str_] = np.array(strings)
    return a

get_array(['a', 'bc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'jk'])
# array([['a', 'bc', 'def', 'gh', 'i', 'jk']], dtype='<U3')
```