Python type hinting and being explicit is still throwing a warning
PyCharm is throwing a yellow warning in the following code, it seems to think that the output of the function is ndarray[Any, dtype]. Should I ignore this error or is there a Pythonic way of dealing with this?
I have also tried np.array(articles, dtype=str) or np.array(articles, dtype=np.str_) but neither solves the problem.
import numpy as np


def load_data() -> np.ndarray[str]:
    articles = []
    with open("data/bbc_raw/001.txt", "rt") as f:
        articles.append(f.read().strip())
    return np.array(articles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = load_data()

Warning:
Expected type 'ndarray[str]', got 'ndarray[Any, dtype]' instead


Try numpy.typing instead.

np.ndarray has two generic params, dtype is the second one. numpy.typing.NDArray[str] should work.

does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472069/set-np-array-of-strings-as-return-type-using-numpy-typing ?

So as others have specified, np.typing.NDArray is indeed the way to go, but it's not quite that simple. In order to specify the type of array, Numpy requires you use its own special version of each type that can appear in an array, e.g.:

str -> np.str_
int -> np.int_
float -> np.float_

Personally, I think the above syntax is not exactly ideal for this, but it seems to be the way it's intended to work.
So to specify your above code with no type errors you can make the return type like so:
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def load_data() -> NDArray[np.str_]:
    articles = []
    with open("data/bbc_raw/001.txt", "rt") as f:
        articles.append(f.read().strip())
    return np.array(articles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = load_data()

Hope this is useful!
